# Adding column to table & adding data right away to column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, alter-table

I am trying to create a new column in an existing table, and using a select statement to do division to create the data I want to insert into my new column.  Several of the statements I have written out will work as separate queries but I have not been able to string together the statements into one single query.

I am still learning SQL and using it with mySQL and PostgreSQL. I took a class last month on SQL and now I am trying to do my own projects to keep my skills sharp.

I am doing some work with elections results from 2012 in MN to use in my tables, to understand data I am working with.

I have been able to alter my table and add a new column with these statements using them by themselves.

```
ALTER TABLE mn2012ct_geom2 ADD COLUMN obama_pct decimal(10,2)
ALTER TABLE mn2012ct_geom2 ADD COLUMN romney_pct decimal(10,2)
```

I was able to use this select statement produce the information I want it to in my terminal application. What I am trying to do here is create a decimal number from the number of votes that the candidate got over the total votes that was cast.

```
SELECT CAST (obama AS DECIMAL) / CAST (uspres_total AS DECIMAL) 
AS obama_pct FROM mn2012ct_geom2

SELECT CAST (romney AS DECIMAL) / CAST (uspres_total AS DECIMAL) 
AS obama_pct FROM mn2012ct_geom2
```

Now I want to have this information adding into the new column I created either with a Alter table statement like I have above or with an insert statement if I create the column before this query.

I have tried a combined query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mn2012ct_geom2 ADD COLUMN obama_pct decimal(10,2) AS
(SELECT CAST (obama AS DECIMAL (10,2)) / CAST (uspres_total AS DECIMAL (10,2)) 
AS obama_pct FROM mn2012ct_geom2);
```

Or using an Insert command like this line instead of the alter table statement

```
INSERT INTO mn2012ct_geom2 (romney_pct) AS
(SELECT CAST (romney AS DECIMAL (10,2)) / CAST (uspres_total AS DECIMAL (10,2)) 
AS romney_pct FROM mn2012ct_geom2);
```

When I try to do that it kicks out an error like this:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: ...mn2012ct_geom2 ADD COLUMN obama_pct decimal(10,2) AS (SELECT...
```

I thought that kind of Alter table and add column or insert would work since that type of format worked when I created a new table using that same select statement.

```
CREATE TABLE obama_pct AS (SELECT CAST (obama AS DECIMAL (10,2)) / CAST (uspres_total     
AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS obama_pct FROM mn2012ct_geom2);
```

Any help for you can provide I would greatly appreciate. I have been trying to google and search here on stackoverflow to find the answer but none of what I have found seems to exactly fit what I am doing it seems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general it's not a good idea to add calculated data to a table. You sometimes need to do it when re-normalizing tables, but usually it's not done.

As Gordon says, the appropriate thing to do here would be to [create a view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html). See [the tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-views.html).

There is no `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... AS`. You can't just make up syntax, you need to look at the [documentation for the command you're interested in](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) to find out how to use it. The `\h` command in `psql` is also useful, eg `\h alter table`.

If you do need to set values in a new column based on calculations from other columns, use [`ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... DEFAULT ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) then `DROP` the `DEFAULT` term after you create the column. It's often better to create the column blank and nullable, then fill it with an `UPDATE` statement.

E.g. untested examples:

```
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE mn2012ct_geom2 ADD COLUMN obama_pct decimal(10,2);

UPDATE mn2012ct_geom2  SET romney_pct = CAST (romney AS DECIMAL (10,2)) / CAST (uspres_total AS DECIMAL (10,2);

COMMIT;
```

or, somewhat uglier:

```
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE mn2012ct_geom2 ADD COLUMN obama_pct decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT (CAST (obama AS DECIMAL (10,2)) / CAST (uspres_total AS DECIMAL (10,2));

ALTER TABLE mn2012ct_geom2 ALTER COLUMN obama_pct DROP DEFAULT;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice and helping me learn. Will take a good look at views and see how they work.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the `update` statement.  For example:

```
ALTER TABLE mn2012ct_geom2 ADD COLUMN obama_pct decimal(10,2);

update mn2012ct_geom2
    set obama_pct = CAST(obama AS DECIMAL) / CAST(uspres_total AS DECIMAL);
```

You might also consider just creating a view to do the calculation:

```
create view v_mn2012ct_geom2 as
    select g.*, CAST(obama AS DECIMAL) / CAST(uspres_total AS DECIMAL) as mn2012ct_geom2
    from mn2012ct_geom2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and appreciate the comment.  After looking at Craig's I saw you left out the set part and why I could not at first get your answer to work.