# How do you create a totals row with percentage in SQL

Tags: sql

I have SQL that generates output like that shown in the attached image under "FIGURE A", but need to expand it to look like "FIGURE B".

Can anyone assist with the SQL?  Thanks

[image: Click here for Figure A & B image]

Answer (score 0):

don't know what Database you are using so try Oracle.
First you need to create a new table include the new column PERCENT_COMPLETED

```
    select STATE,WIDGETS_REQUIRED,WIDGETS_COMPLETED,
           WIDGETS_COMPLETED/WIDGETS_REQUIRED*100 | '%' as PERCENT_COMPLETED
    from table;
```

then you need to insert a new row into it

```
   select 
      'Total' as STATE, 
      sum(WIDGETS_REQUIRED) as WIDGETS_REQUIRED, 
      sum(WIDGETS_COMPLETED) as WIDGETS_COMPLETED,
      sum(WIDGETS_COMPLETED)/sum(WIDGETS_REQUIRED)*100 | '%' as PERCENT_COMPLETED 
  into new_table
  from table;
```

Comment: What does the single vertical bar `|` mean?

Comment: in Oracle it will connect 2 string together. like 'a' | 'b' will be ab

Comment: I see, ANSI SQL has double vertical bars for concatenation, `||`.

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL, I tried this solution. 
First, insert a row with 3 values: STATE, WIDGETS_REQUIRED, WIDGETS_COMPLETED. You can insert these 3 values later, but it is more convenient insert them now.

```
insert into FIGURE_A values
("TOTAL", 48, 33);
```

Second, add a column: percent_complete

```
alter table FIGURE_A
ADD percent_complete decimal(5,2);
```

Here you should notice that you need to add a constraint. See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762302/sql-server-appropriate-datatype-for-holding-percent-values)

So, we need to add the check constraint:

```
alter table FIGURE_A    
ADD constraint chk_range CHECK (percent_complete>=0 and percent_complete<=100);
```

Finally, we just add the percentage values. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement). There are many ways to calculate the percentage. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500336/adding-column-to-table-adding-data-right-away-to-column-in-postgresql) is more suitable for your case, because you need to update, not just calculate.

```
update FIGURE_A
set percent_complete = WIDGETS_COMPLETED*100/WIDGETS_REQUIRED
```

The [final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXsXP.jpg) may look like this.